# Spring rest client, parse part of response object to Set

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson

I create a simple rest client in spring with jackson for a training. I have two models Country and League. 
Country has:

```
private Set<League> leagues;

@JsonProperty("country_id")
private long apiCountryId;
@JsonProperty("country_name")
private String name;
```

and of course getters and setters
League has just id and name.
And now I want to get data from apifootbal, the response looks like:

```
[
    {
        "country_id":"169",
        "country_name":"England",
        "league_id":"62",
        "league_name":"Premier League"
    },
    {
        "country_id":"169",
        "country_name":"England",
        "league_id":"65",
        "league_name":"League 2"
    },
    {
        "country_id":"169",
        "country_name":"England",
        "league_id":"66",
        "league_name":"Nat. League"
    }
]
```

So 2 first elements are the same, 2 last are different for every object, league is not separate object so I can't just take it out. And right now I don't know how to create one Country object what will looks like:

```
id: 169,
name: England,
league: [{
    id:"62",
    name:"Premier League"
}, {
    id:"65",
    name:"League 2"
}, {
    id:"66",
    name:"Nat. League"
}]
```

I know how to create array of country objects where I have all data, but I don't know how separate it to one Country and 3 league objects (and how to add them to collection in country object). One option is to add league_id and league_name to country and after iterate through make league objects from them but it's the only way?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom deserializer and write custom logic to handle such data.

Please refer [deserialize xml to pojo using jackson xml mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805298/deserialize-xml-to-pojo-using-jackson-xml-mapper/51805570#51805570) (The example is in XML but can be similarly used for JSON too)