# JSON Parsing instance type with Array or String

Tags: java, json, jackson, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to parse JSON data using Jackson, found that instance some time as array or String

JSON DATA  instance with String :

```
{
  "Value" : "1"
}
```

JSON DATA instatnce with Array :

```
{
  "Value" : ["ram","kumar"]
}
```

due to this getting error are given below

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot 
deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of VALUE_STRING token
```

In this case how to solve this,thankyou

current java code

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
try { 
     String jsonInString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(products.get(j)); 
       InventoryParser inventoryParser = 
        objectMapper.readValue(jsonInString, InventoryParser.class); 
        System.out.println(inventoryParser.getName()); 
      } 
       catch (IOException e) 
       { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Read into a `map` data structure like so and then process it.

```
final Map<String, Object> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonStr,
        new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
        });
```

Comment: Here I am using POJO class, is that I need to remove as per the code you mentioned.

Comment: Just do the same as above, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom deserializer and write custom logic to handle such data. In the deserializer you can check whether the node is an array or not.

Please refer [deserialize xml to pojo using jackson xml mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805298/deserialize-xml-to-pojo-using-jackson-xml-mapper/51805570#51805570) (The example is in XML but can be similarly used for JSON too by using `ObjectMapper`)